# scp is not working

Tags: scp

I want to transfer all the files of a directory on server 1 to a directory of the same name on server 2 so I am using this command:

```
scp root@176.01.04.128:/../../var/www/backups
```

however, This is the only answer I get:

```
usage: scp [-1246BCpqrv] [-c cipher] [-F ssh_config] [-i identity_file]
           [-l limit] [-o ssh_option] [-P port] [-S program]
           [[user@]host1:]file1 ... [[user@]host2:]file2
```

what am I doing wrong? I have used this command before and had worked fine so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are two things wrong

- only one argument, you need at least two
- `/../../` means "parent of parent of top most dir", this is misleading, at best it will be ignored.

my guess is there is a star (`*`) missing, or a undef variable (between `scp` and `root@...`)

Comment: You were right. I was missing the *. Thank you.